# Get most relevant rates for a list of exchange pairs and rates

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a PostgreSQL table called `rates` with three columns, `pair` which is the pair between two currencies (e.g. `crypto.ETH-fiat.USD`), `rate` which is the conversion rate between the two (e.g. 1.25) and `date` which is a timestamp.

How could I write a query that takes in a list of pairs (e.g. `crypto.ETH-fiat.USD`, `fiat.GBP-fiat.USD`) and a list of timestamp and outputs the closest rate to each timestamp for each pair. There should be no duplicate pairs or timestamps.

Here's an example:

```
Input
Pairs: crypto.ETH-fiat.USD, fiat.GBP-fiat.USD
Timestamps: 2023-04-30 15:12:01.958, 2023-05-01 15:22:12.459, 2022-08-15 02:42:30.326

Output
2023-04-30 15:12:01.958
crypto.ETH-fiat.USD = 1.25
fiat.GBP-fiat.USD = 58.23

2023-05-01 15:22:12.459
crypto.ETH-fiat.USD = 3.25
fiat.GBP-fiat.USD = 18.53

2022-08-15 02:42:30.326
crypto.ETH-fiat.USD = 55.25
fiat.GBP-fiat.USD = 2.5
```